# App-Specific Secure File

Tags: c#, .net, security, file

There is a BCL facility in .net that allows an application to create an encrypted file, which only that self-same application can decrypt.  I have forgotten what namespace / class does this.  Can someone remind me?

If I recall correctly, the facility does not require a password or key to be declared - the whole matter is handled based on the identity of the application.

Comment: I know you can do it based on the user's identity, but I don't know about the app's identity.

Answer (score 3):

Are you thinking of [System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx), which acts as a wrapper to DPAPI?  If so, it can indeed be used for encryption, but readability will be scoped to the user or the machine, not the application.

The only application-scoping of which I am aware that might be what you're remembering is for isolated storage, but that only provides physical isolation on disk -- it does not offer encryption.  You can, however, encrypt the contents of an IsolatedStorageFile, but you will need to do this yourself, using either DPAPI or some other encryption key.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the CryptoStream or IsolatedStorageFile class?